# How to store SQL table data into PHP 2D Array?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an SQL table called grades which has 3 columns: ID, assignment #, and grade letter. I need to save this table full of data into a two dimensional array using PHP and I'm not quite sure how to go about that. I've only come up with one line that so far accomplishes nothing.
Here is my one line:

```
$gradesArray = $conn->query("SELECT ID, assignment, grade FROM grades WHERE ID <= 10");
```

Comment: We do not know what DB extension you are using or which framework you use. We do not know what you mean by 2D array. This question is very unclear.

Comment: I am using mySQL. To give you a more solid understanding of what I am trying to accomplish I am trying to collect the grades data from the mySQL database, and then create a webpage which displays the grade id, assignment number, and letter grade allowing the user to edit the letter grade through a select tag. I decided to approach this problem by storing the data in a 2D array so that I can parse through it and deal with the data that way for the display portion of this program. Does that help at all?